# TTS crashing on some devices

Tags: android

I am getting the following error when loading TTS on some devices (I don't know what they are because this is coming from a remote stacktrace from clients).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidprofessor.android.mmm/com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityGame}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
       at com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityTTS.onCreate(ActivityTTS.java:29)
       at com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityGame.onCreate(ActivityGame.java:96)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
       ... 11 more
```

AND

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidprofessor.android.mmm/com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityGame}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.CHECK_TTS_DATA }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
       at com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityTTS.onCreate(ActivityTTS.java:29)
       at com.droidprofessor.android.mmm.ActivityGame.onCreate(ActivityGame.java:96)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
       ... 11 more
```

In my previous post ([Getting Error when loading TTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674362/getting-error-when-loading-tts)) I made the changes as described.  I added the following

```
                PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity( installIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );

                if( resolveInfo == null ) {
                   // Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.unable_to_access_the_android_market, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                   startActivity( installIntent );
                }
```

Here is the full source of the TTS activity

```
public abstract class ActivityTTS extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    //TEXT TO SPEECH SERVICE
    public static final int CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityTTS";
    private TextToSpeech mTts; //Text to speech library


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //TTS Service
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY);
    }

    /**
     * For TTS
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            if(Logging.DEBUG_LOG) Log.d(TAG, "TTS Response: "+requestCode);
            if (requestCode == CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY) {
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

                    // success, create the TTS instance
                    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);            

                } else {
                    // missing data, install it
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.install_audio_data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity( installIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );

                    if( resolveInfo == null ) {
                       // Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.unable_to_access_the_android_market, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                       startActivity( installIntent );
                    }

                    finish();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            if(Logging.ERROR_LOG) Log.e(TAG, "Unable to access service");
            finish();
        }

    }




    /**
     * Loads when the TTS is ready
     */
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
    }


    /**
     * Speak text
     */
    final void speak(String text) {
        try{
            mTts.stop(); //Stop speaking
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            if (Logging.ERROR_LOG) Log.e(TAG, "TTS Failed - cannot say: "+text );
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Close the Text to Speech Library
        if(mTts != null) mTts.shutdown(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you point out which line in your code matches with where the exception is thrown?

Comment: It happens here from the onCreate() call,  startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY);

Comment: Min SDK in the manifest is set to 4 also (1.6)

Comment: From the looks of it, the device this is being run on doesn't have TTS installed at all.  I'm not sure how that would be possible if they are 1.6 and over.. I think you need to figure out the specs of the device to get much further.  I assume you tested it in the emulator with 1.6 -> 2.2?

Comment: I just tested it on 2.2 and it is working locally, maybe this one is a bit of a mystery

Comment: Its always a good idea to test it on an emulator running 1.6 as well.

Comment: oh yeah, that is what I was using originally

Comment: Ever solved this mystery?