# ActivityNotFoundException - TTS Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm making use of TextToSpeech in my android app.. Some of my users have reported that the application is getting crashed.. On analysis, I found that TTS is the main culprit for crashing.. It throws `ActivityNotFoundException` when trying to install TTS. Here is the code that I use,

```
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            tts.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
            tts.setPitch(1.1f);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            } else {
                speakFunction();
            }
        } else {
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
android.content.NoActivityFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent = (act=android.speech.tts.engine.INSTALL_TTS_DATA} at
```

Please let me know how to fix this?

Update: Below is the code in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Comment: what version of android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880030/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3674497/1168654

Comment: The intent should open Google Play Store/Android Market - is the market/play store installed on the devices which experience the crash?

Comment: did you write the code in the mainfest.xml?

Comment: @DhawalSodha yeaah I already saw the links that you mentioned, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: @Boli-CS Minimum SDK version that I provided in Android Manifest is 8. Do you need any other info from AndroidManifest file?

Comment: @ataulm GPlayStore is installed in the mobile.

Comment: @blackbelt the version of Android is 4.1.2 - Jellybean.

Comment: @Naveen : You can try this link, It first checks if TTS is installed or not.. http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html