# Android Instant App: Is "Text-To-Speech" not allowed in instant apps?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, google-text-to-speech

Instant app is crashing when I try to initialize  `tts` so is it not allowd to use `TextToSpeech` in instant apps?

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Setting tts_default_synth is not accessible from ephemeral package
```

Comment: If you see a `SecurityException`, it typically means it is not allowed. It's still not well documented on all the restricted features, but it may just be impractical to list all of them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472709/text-to-speech-crash-on-instant-apps

Comment: You can also check if your in an instant app install and disable functionality that might be unavailable / crash the app.

Comment: @Praveena Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @BooberBunz Sorry, I stopped working on that. Please try it yourself once.